# How to define the id in Rails input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I define a specific Id into my Rails form ?

```
<%= c.text_field :description, {placeholder: "New comment", class: 'form-control', id: 'comment_text_bar#{post.id}'} %>
```

I've tried `#{}`, or `<%=%>` but it's not working in this case

Comment: Explain *not working*. Do you get any error?

Comment: When i inspect the code that i'd right up, the id= comment_text_bar#{post.id} instead of comment_text_bar23244

Comment: Same with `'comment_text_bar<%=post.id%>'`?

Comment: Yep, i can't use two time <% in the same selector

Comment: But i finally success it with  , :id => "comment_text_bar#{post.id}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use *double quotes(" ")* for *string interpolation*. This should work

```
<%= c.text_field :description, {placeholder: "New comment", class: 'form-control', id: "comment_text_bar#{post.id}"} %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Pavan